# Strange keyboard shortcut icons in Mac OS 10.6.7

Tags: macos, keyboard, icon

Running on Mac OS 10.6.7.  Don't know of any changes that could of happened to make the keyboard shortcuts different.  Tried Googling and found nothing helpful. Anyone know why this happens and how to fix it?

[image: Weird keyboard shortcut icons]

Comment: What is that icon preceding the A? Is it a key? Or a wrench? Or ... something else?

Comment: @VxJasonxV: It is the LastResort entry for the [“Miscellaneous Technical” Unicode block (U+2300–U+23FF)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miscellaneous_Technical_(Unicode_block)). The symbol in the box is U+2331, DIMENSION ORIGIN: `⌱`. See [Apple’s Last Resort Font page](http://developer.apple.com/fonts/LastResortFont/) which links to HTML (glyphs as small images) and PDF (glyphs as embedded outlines) views of the font.

Answer (score 3):

Those look like the placeholder glyphs from the LastResort font. Check your fonts folders and their permissions. Is that the case in every menu all over the system, in every app?

Comment: I think the menu item shortcut symbols usually come from Lucida Grande (`/System/Library/Fonts/LucidaGrande.ttc`).

Answer (score 3):

The why this happened will be hard to guess without some sleuthing and more info. The "what happened" is easier - the font that Finder needs didn't load or has become corrupt/missing.

Assuming you haven't added any fonts recently or use special font software some general next steps would be:

1. make a back up of the system or
   critical files (in case the
   FileSystem or Hard Drive is corrupt
   or failing)
2. reboot in safe mode -
   <kbd>shift</kbd> key held down at
   boot to rebuild and check things in
   general
3. reboot normally - then fire up Font Book and check
   your fonts for problems

Answer (score 2):

One thing to try would've been to clear the font caches: `atsutil databases -remove`. (ATS = Apple Type Services.)