# Dock Notifications Displaying Odd Red Icons Instead

Tags: macos, dock, icon, notifications

Having an odd issue. My dock is showing these strange red icons where normal numerical notifications should be. For example, Thunderbird will display a 3 when I have 3 new messages, but instead it is showing this red A? icon. This happens with all the apps in my dock that display a notification.

See attached screen shot:

[image]

Notice the Thunderbird icon at the top and the Printer icon at the bottom.

Anyway to get my standard notifications back?

Comment: Looks like a system font problem to me.  Has it always been this way on your Mac?  I presume you have tried restarting your computer...?

Comment: No, but I don't know what triggered it. And yes, have restarted several times.

Comment: The glyph looks like one from the [Last Resort font](http://developer.apple.com/fonts/LastResortFont/) that is used when the requested font is not available. Most of the system UI uses Lucida Grande, but I am not sure if this also applies to your particular dock icon badges. Use *Font Book* to check that **Lucida Grande** is present, enabled, and validates correctly. Related: [AD 11909](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/11909/3349).

Comment: @Chris the related question has this answer: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11909/strange-keyboard-shortcut-icons-in-mac-os-10-6-7/13435#13435

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like it might be a problem with a system font.  Try this...

1. Open Font Book (in `/Applications`)
2. Select the "All Fonts" collection in the left-hand pane
3. Click any font in the right-hand pane to focus that pane
4. Select all the fonts using Edit -> Select All or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
5. In the File menu, click "Validate Fonts"

If any fonts are corrupt, this method should alert you to the problem.

[image: Font Book - Validate Fonts menu option]

[image: Font Book - Font Validation window]

Comment: This in combination with Chris's comment above solved it. Thanks!

Comment: @mxmissile You're welcome -- glad you got it fixed!